# Assigning code to push button for GUI in tcl/tk

Tags: perl, tcl, tk-toolkit

I am new to this 'GUI' but i want to create a GUI in tcl/tk with one push button and one display to show the output. I have gone through several examples of GUI but i coundnt find an example to assign a code/script to a push button. So can anyone help me on this?

Is it possible to assign a perl script to a tcl/tk GUI code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean you want to execute a callback sub in the event that a certain button is clicked? And this callback sets the contents of another element?

Comment: @amon,yes for the first question but I am not able to understand the second one.

Comment: This question reminds me of a small gui I just wrote last week (to test things). Just 3 buttons, 1 text widget, buttons to start processes, text widget to display their output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your exact problem is because what you want to do is really simple. Just use the `-command` option:

```
pack [button .b -text Hello -command {puts "Hello World"}]
```

If the code you want to execute is in a string, then you can simply do:

```
set code {
    puts "Hello World"
}
pack [button .b -text Hello -command $code]
```

If you want to execute a function:

```
proc say_hello {} {
    puts "Hello World"
}
pack [button .b -text Hello -command say_hello]
```

If the button you want to assign the command to already exist then just assign it to the `-command` option:

```
# Assuming button .b already exist:
.b configure -command say_hello
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i want the code to run my tcl file when the push button is pressed. i.e. for ex. if i have a file "test.tcl" how am i supposed to give that?????

Comment: That's a different question that has nothing to do with buttons. You can simplify it by asking "how can my tcl script execute another tcl script". For that, read the manual on `exec`.

Comment: To clarify, it would be something like `exec tclsh your_script.tcl`

Comment: ,I want to run my script through GUI using push buttons so if I just run exec tclsh your_script.tcl that will not be through GUI but just a normal script,right??hope i have made myself clear

Comment: so  `pack [button .b -text Hello -command exec tclsh your_script.tcl]` is this fine???

Comment: thanks for your answer,it helped me a lot. I would be greatly obliged if you would help me out in my future regarding GUI